# What is the right approach when Kotlin function does not take nullable type

Tags: kotlin

So I was solving Koans problem and through my overly complex solution bumped into a thing that bothers me. I was using Int.compareTo() function on nullable types. It is "easy" if the first one is nullable because I just write:

```
val a : Int? = 1
val b : Int = 1
a?.compareTo(b)
```

But if b is nullable, then I was not able to get it to work, maybe I missed something somewhere? So what to do when this is the case?

```
val a : Int? = 1
val b : Int? = 2
a?.compareTo(b)
```

I get a syntax error saying "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."

But, when I introduce this:

```
val a : Int? = 1
val b : Int? = 2
val x : Int = b ?: 0;
o1?.compareTo(x)
```

It works but it feels like it is not the right way to do this. Is there a better way?

Comment: You need to define "work". What should null compare to 42 be? What should 42 compare to null be? What should null compare to null be?

Comment: You need to define "work". What should null compare to 42 be? What should 42 compare to null be? What should null compare to null be?

Comment: Comparing nullable primitives is generally pretty complicated. Using the default `compareTo` implementation in these cases is only really possible the way you've already shown. The first thing you'd have to decide is what you want the results of comparisons against `null` values to result in, then you can write your own solution for comparing them.

Comment: I agree that it is hard to compare null value with an existing one, but let's say I am trying to find a way to compare primitives that are not exiting in Kotlin as everything is an object. For example Python I believe treats everything as an object but (5 < 4) == True exists.

Comment: I realised above is not true, there are primitives in a way and can be compared when it is not a nullable object in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
val a: Int? = 1
val b: Int? = 2
b?.let {
   a?.compareTo(b)
}
```

`let` block will be executed only if b is not null.

Or just

```
if (a != null && b != null) {
   a.compareTo(b)
}
```

I think second solution is very clear and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

The Int.compareTo() method's signature is not defined for nullable arguments so it's not possible to do without ensuring null safety of the argument by e.g. using an elvis operator just as you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to implement your solution without nullability. But if you still need it and if it's safe to assume that `null==0` you should not use the `?.` method call. It'll return you an `Int?` as well. Just map both `null` integers to 0.

```
(a?:0).compareTo(b?:0)
```

Comment: sir, the expression `(null?:0).compareTo(-1) ` violate the rule. it return a positive number `1`.

Comment: ... which means that `null` is greater than `-1`, which is what you expect if you assume that `null` is equivalent to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The only better way is to implement `compareTo` yourself. The default compare does not know what result you want when you compare i.e. `12` to `null` or `null` to `null`. It only knows how to compare actual numbers. I think your best way is to implement the behaviour you want for dealing with `null`s.

Example implementation:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(compareNullableInts(null, 2))    // -1
    println(compareNullableInts(null, null)) // 0
    println(compareNullableInts(2, null))    // 1
    println(compareNullableInts(10, 5))      // 1
}


fun compareNullableInts(a: Int?, b: Int?): Int {
    if (a == null && b == null) return 0
    if (a == null) return -1
    if (b == null) return 1
    return a.compareTo(b)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the expression should be like this:

```
val result = b?.let { a?.compareTo(b) ?: -1 } ?: 1;
```

### Examples

```
> a = 1      b = 2          --->  -1

> a = null   b = 2          --->  -1

> a = null   b = -1          --->  -1

> a = 1      b = null       --->   1

> a = -1      b = null       --->   1

> a = null   b = null       --->   1 // the order is no matter
```

**IF** you want to let `null` compare `null` return `0` then the expression is a bit long:

```
val result = b?.let { a?.compareTo(b) ?: -1 } ?: a?.let { 1 } ?: 0;
```

**Note**: you don't care about the performance, since `let` function is an inline function. which means it will generates the code like as below in java:

```
int result =  b != null ? a != null ? a.compareTo(b) : -1 : a != null ? 1 : 0;
```